# what is the proper way to build angular library

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-library

Hi I am using angular 8 workplace to build multiple applications. In this project I need to build a lot libraries which could be shared with multiple applications.

But I ran into problem with debugging my angular library since I have to build it every time I have made a change on the library.

I am relatively new to building angular libraries. I am not sure what is the proper way to build an library. Currently What I did is to build the component or library inside my main app to make sure it working 100% then I extract it to angular library.

How can I achieve that I can immediately see the change if I have made some changes in the library while I am developing locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your library suppose you have a **CustomLibModule**,

In your app.module, you can have it in this way:

```
import { CustomLibModule } from 'projects/common-table/src/lib/custom-lib.module';
//import { CustomLibModule } from 'custom-library';
```

While working, keep the first import, you can debug easily, once you are done with all changes, build it and then uncomment the second import and remove the first.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. Is this the only way “making the relative path” to do the debugging when the library is outside of the main application?

Comment: I have built few libraries and I follow this process. To be frank. I am not sure if there is any other way.